# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN: [0 nan; 240 291]'

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uipopovercontroller

I am displaying PickerView inside UIPopOver.

For that I have used the following code on  button click to display PopOver.

```
- (IBAction)btnSelectTeachers:(id)sender {

    UIView *masterView;
    CGRect pickerFrame ;
    if(appDelegate.isOSVersionGreaterThan7)
    {
        masterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 240, 216)];
        pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 240, 216);
    }
    else
    {
        masterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 216)];
        pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 216);
    }
    UIPickerView *myPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    [myPicker setDataSource: self];
    [myPicker setDelegate: self];
    myPicker.tag=3;
    [myPicker selectRow:selectedTeacherIndex inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    [myPicker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
    self.myPickerView=myPicker;
    [masterView addSubview:myPicker];
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    viewController.view = masterView;
    viewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = viewController.view.frame.size;
    self.popoverController =[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame
                                            inView:self.view
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                          animated:YES];

    [self.myPickerView reloadAllComponents];

    /*if(selectedTeacherIndex<0)
    {
        selectedTeacherIndex=0;
    }*/
    [self.myPickerView selectRow:selectedTeacherIndex+1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    [self pickerView:self.myPickerView didSelectRow:selectedTeacherIndex+1 inComponent:0];
}
```

Its working fine for most of the time, but sometimes it gets terminated with above exception.

Comment: Place break-point in this method and step debug your code your will get know which frame in problem.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have this exception coming in, but I can't reproduce it myself

Comment: @vrwim not yet...